# Error in Windows Image System Manager (WISM) to open Install.win

Tags: windows, system

I just want to open install.win file to make .clg file but won't open.

**Error:**

Error opening Windows image at C:\Users\Vahid\Desktop\install.wim
Details: An Item with the same key has already added.

**It's the log of Error:**

10:19 PM : 
10:19 PM : Error opening Windows image at C:\Users\Vahid\Desktop\install.wim.

10:19 PM : 
10:19 PM : System.ArgumentException: An item with the same key has already been added.
   at System.ThrowHelper.ThrowArgumentException(ExceptionResource resource)
   at System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2.Insert(TKey key, TValue value, Boolean add)
   at System.Collections.ObjectModel.KeyedCollection`2.AddKey(TKey key, TItem item)
   at System.Collections.ObjectModel.KeyedCollection`2.InsertItem(Int32 index, TItem item)
   at System.Collections.ObjectModel.Collection`1.Add(T item)
   at Microsoft.ComponentStudio.ComponentPlatformInterface.WimInfo..ctor(String wimPath)
   at Microsoft.ComponentStudio.ComponentPlatformInterface.Cpi.OpenWim(String wimPath)
   at Microsoft.ComponentStudio.ImagePicker.GetImageInfoFromPath(String path)
   at Microsoft.ComponentStudio.ImagePicker.ValidateImageFileOrFolder(String fileOrFolder)

Answer (score 0):

You must check if your install.wim file is 64bit your running windows must be 64bit too.

Comment: I think you mean I should change the Windows ISO to same own windows ?? right ?

Comment: if you mean install.wim file yes that's true.